# pyspark: reduce size of JSON variable

Tags: json, pyspark

I'm trying to analyse a JSON file that contains data from the Twitter API. The file is 2GB so it takes ages to load or attempt to run any analysis on.

So in pyspark I load it up:

```
 df = sqlContext.read.json('/data/statuses.log.2014-12-30.gz')
```

this takes about 20 minutes as does any further analysis so I want to look at just a small section of the dataset so I can test my scripts quickly and easily. I tried

```
df = df.head(1000)
```

but this seems to alter the dataset somehow, so when I try

```
print(df.groupby('lang').count().sort(desc('count')).show())
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'
```

Is there any way I can reduce to size of the data so I can play around with it without having to wait ages each time?

Comment: if loading is taking time, try to specify schema when you do `read.json`. Not specifying schema makes it scan data to figure out what the datatypes might be, which may explain why its taking so long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
 df = df.limit(1000)
```